# Handling RFC2046 media types in UWP

Tags: c#, svg, uwp, win-universal-app, mime

I'm using Microsoft UWP platform and my application needs to handle media types according to [MIME Part Two: Media Types [**RFC2046**]](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2046.txt). My program is based on the SVG 1.1 specification. One section in the specification declares that the default value for one attribute is **"text/css" [[RFC2318](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2318.txt)**]. Does this mean that the **RFC2318** is part of the **RFC2046**?

I tried to googling some C# related libraries and found out that [System.Net.Mime namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mime(v=vs.110).aspx) could possibly support it? However, this namespace is not available on UWP platform.
Also Google has made a Java [MediaType](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/net/MediaType.html)-class which had some references to RFC2046 but it's also closed source.

**Are there any projects I could use to implement [RFC2046](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2046.txt)? I can also convert possible projects from Java to C#.** I basically need a solution that parses, verifies and converts parameter RFC2046 strings to objects.

Comment: Neither the string "css" nor the string "2318" appear anywhere in that RFC link. Also, it's not clear whether you're dealing with HTTP payloads, or e-mail, or something else.

Comment: @Peter Torr I'm dealing with SVG documents. I think the RFC2046 defines "media types", but the RFC2046 defines "text/css media type". Probably there exists a list of all defined media types somewhere with their own 'RFC' IDs.

Comment: If you just want to render, [XAML support SVG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/WINDOWS.UI.XAML.MEDIA.IMAGING.SVGIMAGESOURCE). Direct2D also has some support that [might be helpful](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt790715%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @Peter Torr: That's new info, thanks. I've played with the Win2D library's SVG support earlier. I edited the question to be more clear.